# Is there a way for a user to temporarily remove its own group membership within a script?

Tags: unix, users, groups

I'm writing a script which will be used to "detect" whether a generic, no-frills, user account has access to certain files.  Basically a user which only has membership in the "staff" group or something to that effect.

I don't necessarily want to create a new Unix account just for this, though.  I'd much rather use one of the accounts our group currently owns, but maybe remove its own group memberships within the detection script.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could hack something up using sudo and groupadd/groupdel/groupmod, but this sounds like an accident waiting to happen.  Couldn't you handle this simply by setting the proper ownership and permissions then have your script verify those?

Comment: I can't actually modify the groups settings (they are handled by our corporate LDAP overlords) so I was looking for something else that could temporarily do it.  Also, I can't just "set" the proper ownership and permissions because different groups lock down their file systems differently.  Our first run is to simply make sure they have basic security measures in place...and our plan is to test this by seeing if a generic account can actually access their files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what's available using the `groups` command.

As for changing it, these are set by root at login time using `setgroups(2)`, which must be called as root.  So the answer is no.  Not without using @yoonix' sudo solution, or something similar.

Comment: And the reason for this is that group membership can be (and traditionally was) used for removing privileges: `chmod 705` works. See https://lwn.net/Articles/621612/ for further details.